# creating formatted NSDate using NSDateFormatter or mktime

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval, time-t

I'm just trying to create a `NSDate` object with string as:`2011-02-10 4:30:45`

Take a look at the code:

**Approach OBJC:**

```
-(NSDate *)get_date_df:(NSString *)dstr
{
    NSLog(@"1> %@",dstr);

    NSDateFormatter *df_in = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
    [df_in setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];   
    NSDate *d = [df_in dateFromString:dstr];

    NSLog(@"2> %@",d);

    NSLog(@"3> %@",[df_in stringFromDate:d]);

    return d;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
1> 2011-02-10 4:30:45
2> 2011-02-09 23:00:45 +0000
3> 2011-02-10 04:30:45
```

So why is `2>` getting printed wrong?
Suppose at `2011-02-10 4:20:45`, I try setting up a LocalNotification with that date, it fires instantly because the processor assumes the time is already expired!

```
UILocalNotification *lnf = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[lnf setFireDate:[self get_date_df:@"2011-02-10 4:30:45"]];
[lnf setAlertBody:@"WTF"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:lnf];
[lnf release];
```

And, I've already tried setting up various `TimeZones` and `NSLocale` for `en_US, en_FR`. No help.

**Approach C:**

And FYI now I'm switching to C, trying something with:

```
-(NSDate *)get_date_c:(const char *)date_str
{
    char date[10][6] = {0};
    sscanf(date_str,"%[0-9] - %[0-9] - %[0-9] %[0-9] : %[0-9] : %[0-9]",date[0],date[1],date[2],date[3],date[4],date[5]);   

    struct tm *t_info = (struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
    t_info->tm_sec = atoi(date[5]);
    t_info->tm_min = atoi(date[4]);
    t_info->tm_hour = atoi(date[3]);
    t_info->tm_mday = atoi(date[2]);
    t_info->tm_mon = atoi(date[1]);
    t_info->tm_year = atoi(date[0]);
    NSLog(@"ans: %f",(double)mktime(t_info));
    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:mktime(t_info)];
    free(t_info);
    return d;
}
```

Output:
`ans: -1.000000`
There again I'm stuck with converting `time_t` to `NSTimeInterval`.
So, thanks in advance if you could help me out with any approach :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your input string and format **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** you didn't specify the timezone. So it defaults to UTC.

Comment: but, in that case log #3 should've also printed time in UTC

Comment: in log #2 the thing I missed out was using:

     `NSLog(@"2> %@",[d descriptionWithLocale:locale_str]);`

Got another hint from [link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2741171&tstart=90)

Comment: or set your date format as `[df_in setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];` with the string as `@"2011-02-11 21:21:45 PDT"`

Comment: @sid but now we know where you live :)

Comment: haha, then what about coming over to my house this weekend for a cup of tea?

Comment: @sid I'd love to, but you live in a different hemisphere :)